# How to separate comments into pages

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, comments

I am getting comments from my MySQL database with jQuery Ajax function and I receive JSON array.

commentsLoad.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$newsid = $_GET['newsid'];

$comments=array();
$commentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM comments
where fk_news like ".$newsid;
$result = $conn->query($commentsQuery);
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             $comments[]=array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['cnick'], 'text' => $row['ctext'], 'date' => $row['cdate']);                                                                      
        }
    }
                echo json_encode($comments);
                exit;
?>
```

my Javascript:

```
    $('.toggleComments').click(function(){  
    var commentsPosition = $(this).closest('div').next().find('.userComments');
    var newsid = $(this).data('newsid');        
    if(!$(this).hasClass('commentsReady')){ 
        $(this).addClass('commentsReady');
        console.log("Getting comments...");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: commentsUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            data:{newsid:newsid},
            success: function(comments){
                $.each(comments, function(i, komentar){
                    addComment(commentsPosition,komentar);
                })
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }               
        });
    }       
});
```

I want to separate these comments to 5 comments on each page.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is **pagination**. You'll also need to look in to the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit your comments to 5 comments per page, use the limit cause like:

```
$commentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM comments where fk_news like ".$newsid limit 5;
```

If you want to limit and get the latest 5 you can (in addition to above) add order by like:

```
$commentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM comments where fk_news like ".$newsid limit 5 order by cdate desc;
```

If you want to pull all the comments but show pagination so users only see 5 comments, then click on next (or page number) then skip to next one, you can do so using any JS or JQuery pagination plugin like: [SimplePagination.js](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)